# Header with Left, Right and Centered elements

Tags: html, css, header, css-float, css-position

I am having trouble creating a header with left, right and centered elements - I keep trying but i am unable to get the elements positioned in that specific layout with the title being centered at all times

Can anybody help? I feel that I am close but i can't get it to work!

**CODE HERE: https://jsfiddle.net/4a25nqb4/**

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="top">
               <div id="social">
                    <span class="fa fa-facebook"></span>
                    <span class="fa fa-instagram"></span>
                    <span class="fa fa-youtube"></span>
               </div>
                <p id="website">www.AlmostFreeFurniture.com</p>

                <h1 id="title">Almost Free Furniture</h1>


            </div>



        </div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0px;
}

.top {
    height: 40px;
    background-color:black;
    color:red;
    margin-top:4px solid orange;
    margin-top:10px;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    text-align:center;
}

#social, #website, #title {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

#social {
    float:right;
}

#website {
    float:left;
}

#title {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The floats effect the amount of available area to center in. Because the item on the left is larger then the right, the center between them is closer to the right. If you'll position the left and right items absolutely, the centering mechanism will ignore them ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4a25nqb4/1/)):

```
#social {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}

#website {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `display: flex` instead of `display: table`, and then you can push the #social over to the right with `order`:

```
* {
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0px;
}

.top {
    height: 40px;
    background-color:black;
    color:red;
    margin-top:4px solid orange;
    margin-top:10px;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    text-align:center;
}

#social, #website, #title {
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
    vertical-align: top;
}
#website { overflow-x: hidden; }
#social {
    text-align: right;
    -webkit-order: 1;
    order: 1;
}
#title {
    text-align: center;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4a25nqb4/

To give #title more room, you can either  give it a `flex: 2` or something like `flex-basis: 50%` or thereabouts.

Answer (score 0):

Set width of this elements to 33.33%

```
#social, #website, #title {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 33.33%;
}
```

Next give text-align for elements left, center and right.